# MacBook Pro Panics Way More Than It Should

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I've got a 16-inch 2019 MacBook Pro, 2.3 GHz Intel i9 and over the last few months it has started to panic now and then. Way more than it should.

I started with the usual things, making sure everything was updated, there was no unnecessary software installed, cleaned up caches, temp files and the like. Even starting in Safe Mode did nothing different. It would still panic once or twice a day.

So I backed it up, reformatted the SSD and reinstalled macOS fresh. I restored from Time Machine using Migration Assistant and only restored my user folder, no apps.

After running for a week or so I had cut back on the number of panics, I think it was just one that week. Over the next few weeks I slowly installed a few apps, one at a time waiting a few days or so between installations, to see if there was an obvious culprit. Just my needful basics: 1Password, TorGuard VPN, Brave, Firefox, etc. and I stated to get a few panics but the number was way down from before the reinstall.

As I use the Mac (general computing, word processing, web browsers, mail.app, VPN now and then) I continue to get the panics but the frequency is reduced, but when I do get a panic it's usually in Safari. So I switch to Brave and while a little better, not substantially so. Trying Firefox it remains about the same.

I continue to get the occasional (once or maybe twice a week) notification that the computer was restarted because of a problem, when waking the Mac.

So the frequency of panics is a *little* lower than before I did a clean reinstall it is still way more than it should be at 3-5 times a week. Unfortunately the panic log that is sent to Apple means nothing to me and I was wondering if someone conversant in panic logs might have a quick look and see if they see a culprit. The one below happened when I was in Firefox reading a web page. The system locked up, screen went black, displayed the panic screen and rebooted.

I am starting to think that this is a hardware issue and maybe I need to trade this beast in for a new MacBook Pro, sigh...

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80153d38f3): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801535a0a5, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff837aa40074, CR3: 0x000000034f6ba064, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x000000000fea9000, RBX: 0xffffff837aa40000, RCX: 0xffffff7f80000000, RDX: 0x0000000000170124
RSP: 0xffffffd0697b3be0, RBP: 0xffffffd0697b3c10, RSI: 0x00000000000007fe, RDI: 0xffffff850ed6d400
R8:  0x0000000000000014, R9:  0xffffff802c800000, R10: 0x0000000080028864, R11: 0x0000008080000000
R12: 0xffffff7f90800000, R13: 0xffffff802d1bf528, R14: 0xffffff850ed6d400, R15: 0xffffff850ed6d400
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff801535a0a5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff837aa40074, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x4, PL: 0, VF: 1

Panicked task 0xffffff8b77cba000: 81 threads: pid 526: firefox
Backtrace (CPU 4), panicked thread: 0xffffff951262a550, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffd0697b3590 : 0xffffff8015283e2d 
0xffffffd0697b35e0 : 0xffffff80153e3cb6 
0xffffffd0697b3620 : 0xffffff80153d350d 
0xffffffd0697b3670 : 0xffffff8015223a60 
0xffffffd0697b3690 : 0xffffff80152841fd 
0xffffffd0697b37b0 : 0xffffff80152839b6 
0xffffffd0697b3810 : 0xffffff8015b164bf 
0xffffffd0697b3900 : 0xffffff80153d38f3 
0xffffffd0697b3a80 : 0xffffff80153d35e2 
0xffffffd0697b3ad0 : 0xffffff8015223a60 
0xffffffd0697b3af0 : 0xffffff801535a0a5 
0xffffffd0697b3c10 : 0xffffff801536f38a 
0xffffffd0697b3c50 : 0xffffff8015351598 
0xffffffd0697b3cc0 : 0xffffff80153500cd 
0xffffffd0697b3d00 : 0xffffff801535146b 
0xffffffd0697b3d30 : 0xffffff8015350608 
0xffffffd0697b3d70 : 0xffffff801533a8e2 
0xffffffd0697b3ec0 : 0xffffff8015339e93 
0xffffffd0697b3ef0 : 0xffffff80153b61a8 
0xffffffd0697b3fa0 : 0xffffff8015224246 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff951262a550): firefox

Mac OS version:
21E258

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:45:05 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B6F8637B-0844-355F-8C82-60FA06149384
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000015000000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8015200000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000015010000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8015210000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 604475789561
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000008cbd909407
  Sleep   : 0x00000049c5295334 0x0000510ddd729364 0x0000003de3420bbc
  Wake    : 0x00000049f914e4b4 0x0000535bf2adaa32 0x00000049d806bbec
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Foreign : 0xffffff802b497000 - 0xffffff802b4a5000
  Native  : 0xffffff8043858000 - 0xffffffa043858000
  Readonly: 0xffffff8510524000 - 0xffffff86a9ebd000
  Metadata: 0xfffffff5f80e3000 - 0xfffffff618267000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffff618267000 - 0xfffffff61e267000

last started kext at 191412986646: @filesystems.smbfs   4.0 (addr 0xffffff7fae738000, size 483328)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  4.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5440.11
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   127
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.8
>!ABridgeAudio!C    240.6
>!AGFXHDA   140.3
>!A!IKBLGraphics    18.0.5
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.5.7
>!AMuxControl2  6.5.7
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.5.7
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  126.100.13
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.5.7
>!ABacklight    180.5
>!AMCCSControl  1.15
@UVCService 1
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>BridgeAudioCommunication   240.6
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.5
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   583.100.10
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1934.101.3
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  228.1
>!AHS!BDriver   5440.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AActuatorDriver   5440.11
>!AMultitouchDriver 5440.11
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5440.6
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!UAudio    415.11
>!AAudioClockLibs   140.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.0.8
>!AHDA!C    340.2
|IOHDA!F    340.2
|IOAudio!F  340.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  6.5.7
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1040.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1040.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.0.8
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  594
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@!AGPUWrangler  6.5.7
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.5.7
|IOGraphics!F   594
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.14
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1040.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  533.100.11
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  210.101.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  456.100.7
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  456.100.7
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.2.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: If you keep track of the front most app, is it always Firefox?

Comment: Nope, it has been Safari, Brave, Chrome, and mail.app, but it is always the frontmost app unless it happened while the Mac was sleeping, then I am not sure.

Comment: One additional easy diagnostic is a UEFI-based extended memory test tool which has significantly expanded coverage over Apple Diagnostics: https://www.memtest86.com/memtest86.html (Download the free version and `dd` the `memtest86-usb.img` image onto a flash drive, then boot from it.) Run that and see if you get any errors (it'll take a while!). Your symptoms suggest marginal DRAM as a possible culprit so we should rule that out.

Comment: @pion, thx for that tip! I ran memtest and it found 166 errors which confirms what I believe. Unfortunately memtest **crashed** (grrr....) when done and I couldn't save the logfile. But I think it may be time for another MacBook Pro. Fortunately Apple will give me almost $1k for my trade in, so there is that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely sounds like a hardware issue.

Your kernel panics indicates that the kernel itself is experiencing page faults. That is not supposed to happen.

Page faults in the kernel happen either due to hardware error or kernel bugs. The frequency of panics you have mean that it is not just an Apple kernel software bug - otherwise everyone would have panics all the time. If you had a third party kernel extension installed with bugs - that might explain this. However, you said that you have started over with a fresh macOS installation and still seeing the problem.

This is very clear indication of a hardware problem.

You could try cleaning your MacBook Pro - making sure there's no build ups of dust. It is a long shot, but it might help the problem.