# MacBook Pro 16-inch 2019 restarts after sleep or locking the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

Sometimes my MacBook Pro restarts after a while of being asleep. Other times it restarts after a while of being with the screen locked.

I have macOS Monterrey, but this is has been happening before the OS upgrade.

This is the error report I got from the system after the reboot.

```
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 0, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 4
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 2 acks but received 1 after 6578077 loops in 1152000000 ticks
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801dbe67c7): Double fault at 0xffffff801da3ba53, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffffd097647fe8, CR3: 0x0000000031d9a000, CR4: 0x&lx
RAX: 0x00000000003626e0, RBX: 0x0000000000000008, RCX: 0x000000000000000e, RDX: 0xffffff8573266b70
RSP: 0x0000000000000001, RBP: 0x0xffffffd097647ff0, RSI: 0xffffffd097648000, RDI: 0x0000000000000008
R8:  0xffffffd097648010, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffffd097648000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0xffffffd097648010, RIP: 0x0000000000010086, CS:  0xffffff801da3ba53, SS:  0x0000000000000008
Error code: 0x0000000000000010
 @:506969772
Panicked task 0xffffff8572a566a0: 282 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffff8573266b70, Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801d9562c0 : 0xffffff801da9c00d 
0xffffff801d956310 : 0xffffff801dbf5d85 
0xffffff801d956350 : 0xffffff801dbe5763 
0xffffff801d9563a0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d9563c0 : 0xffffff801da9c3dd 
0xffffff801d9564e0 : 0xffffff801da9bb96 
0xffffff801d956540 : 0xffffff801e318649 
0xffffff801d9565b0 : 0xffffff801dbe67c7 
0xffffff801d9566c0 : 0xffffff801e31e7a8 
0xffffff801d9566d0 : 0xffffff801da3c2df 
0xffffffd097648000 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648320 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648390 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd0976483b0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd0976486d0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648740 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648760 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648a80 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648af0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648b10 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648e30 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648ea0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648ec0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd0976491e0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649250 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649270 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649590 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649600 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649620 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649940 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd0976499b0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd0976499d0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649cf0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649d60 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649d80 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a0a0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764a110 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764a130 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a450 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764a4c0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764a4e0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a800 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764a870 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764a890 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764abb0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764ac20 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764ac40 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764af60 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764afd0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764aff0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764b310 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764b380 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764b3a0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764b6c0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764b730 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764b750 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764ba70 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764bae0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764bb00 : 0xffffff801dbfb525 
0xffffffd09764bc30 : 0xffffff801dbe7de9 
0xffffffd09764bc50 : 0xffffff801dbf4170 
0xffffffd09764bc90 : 0xffffff801eb3532e 
0xffffffd09764bce0 : 0xffffff801eb39783 
0xffffffd09764bd00 : 0xffffff801e27f4b2 
0xffffffd09764bd50 : 0xffffff801e2cc116 
0xffffffd09764bdd0 : 0xffffff801e2425b6 
0xffffffd09764be40 : 0xffffff801e23f314 
0xffffffd09764be90 : 0xffffff801e23c6c0 
0xffffffd09764bee0 : 0xffffff801e23c55a 
0xffffffd09764bf20 : 0xffffff801e25a0ee 
0xffffffd09764bf60 : 0xffffff801e2596f7 
0xffffffd09764bfa0 : 0xffffff801da3b18e 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff8573266b70): kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
21A559

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:23 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 19BD4E1B-0268-3EE0-BC66-91F035BC9429
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001d800000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff801da00000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001d810000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff801da10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801d900000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 7152286893028
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000068145850782
  Sleep   : 0x00000cdeda23bcf3 0x000025e340cbd772 0x00000bf3e7b6326c
  Wake    : 0x00000c009a0e8068 0x000027de9b174ad8 0x00000c0078fe5032
Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xffffff8033c63000 - 0xffffff8033c70000
Native    : 0xffffff8065139000 - 0xffffffa065139000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffe031669000 - 0xffffffe05197e000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffe05197e000 - 0xffffffe05d97e000
last started kext at 13088153156511: >!UAudio   412.8 (addr 0xffffff7fb5c35000, size 364544)
last stopped kext at 13309011739608: >!UAudio   412.8 (addr 0xffffff7fb5c35000, size 364544)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.6.5
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   125
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5010.1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.0.7
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.7
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.434
>!ABridgeAudio!C    200.8
>!A!IKBLGraphics    18.0.2
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.4.9
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.4.9
>!AMuxControl2  6.4.9
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  126.40.1
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.4.9
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   200.8
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.2
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 452.30.4
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   582.40.4
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@filesystems.apfs   1933.41.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  228
>!AHS!BDriver   5010.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AActuatorDriver   5400.25
>!AMultitouchDriver 5400.25
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5400.30
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   100.9.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.0.7
|IOAudio!F  300.10
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.0.7
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.7
>!AGraphicsControl  6.4.9
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1010.2
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1000.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.4
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  593
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGPUWrangler  6.4.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.4.9
|IOGraphics!F   593
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.0
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.0
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.9
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1000.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  532.40.7
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  209.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  452.30.4
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  452.30.4
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.1.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801dbe67c7): panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801dbe67c7):  at 0x00000000ffffffff, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000000000008, CR2: 0xffffff801d9566e0, CR3: 0x0000000000000000, CR4: 0x&lx
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff801d9566e0, RCX: 0xffffff801d9566d0, RDX: 0xffffff801e31e7a8
RSP: 0xffffffd097648000, RBP: 0x0xffffff801da3c2df, RSI: 0x000000000000000f, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffffd097648010, R9:  0x0000000000000008, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffffd097647fe8, R15: 0xffffffd097648010
RFL: 0x0000000000000000, RIP: 0x0000000000000000, CS:  0xffffffd097648000, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Error code: 0xffffffd097648000panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801dbe67c7):  at 0x0000000000000008, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000038210000, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000000000008, CR4: 0x&lx
RAX: 0x0000000000000007, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff801da3ba53, RDX: 0x0000000000000008
RSP: 0x0000000000010086, RBP: 0x0xffffffd097647ff0, RSI: 0x0000000000000010, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000000000, RIP: 0x0000000000000000, CS:  0x0000000000000000, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Error code: 0x0000000000000000
 @:0
Panicked task 0xffffff8572a566a0: 282 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 0), panicked thread: 0xffffff8573266b70, Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801d954cd0 : 0xffffff801da9c00d 
0xffffff801d954d20 : 0xffffff801dbf5d85 
0xffffff801d954d60 : 0xffffff801dbe5763 
0xffffff801d954db0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d954dd0 : 0xffffff801da9c3dd 
0xffffff801d954ef0 : 0xffffff801da9bb96 
0xffffff801d954f50 : 0xffffff801e318649 
0xffffff801d954fc0 : 0xffffff801dbe5b53 
0xffffff801d955140 : 0xffffff801dbe5838 
0xffffff801d955190 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d9551b0 : 0xffffff801dab85cd 
0xffffff801d955380 : 0xffffff801da9bf5a 
0xffffff801d9553d0 : 0xffffff801dbf5d85 
0xffffff801d955410 : 0xffffff801dbe5763 
0xffffff801d955460 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d955480 : 0xffffff801da9c3dd 
0xffffff801d9555a0 : 0xffffff801da9bb96 
0xffffff801d955600 : 0xffffff801e318649 
0xffffff801d955670 : 0xffffff801dbe5b53 
0xffffff801d9557f0 : 0xffffff801dbe5838 
0xffffff801d955840 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d955860 : 0xffffff801dab85cd 
0xffffff801d955a30 : 0xffffff801da9bf5a 
0xffffff801d955a80 : 0xffffff801dbf5d85 
0xffffff801d955ac0 : 0xffffff801dbe5763 
0xffffff801d955b10 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d955b30 : 0xffffff801da9c3dd 
0xffffff801d955c50 : 0xffffff801da9bb96 
0xffffff801d955cb0 : 0xffffff801e318649 
0xffffff801d955d20 : 0xffffff801dbe5b53 
0xffffff801d955ea0 : 0xffffff801dbe5838 
0xffffff801d955ef0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d955f10 : 0xffffff801db07790 
0xffffff801d956080 : 0xffffff801dbd5439 
0xffffff801d9560c0 : 0xffffff801dbe573e 
0xffffff801d956110 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d956130 : 0xffffff801db1c8b8 
0xffffff801d956270 : 0xffffff801dbeb417 
0xffffff801d9562c0 : 0xffffff801da9c00d 
0xffffff801d956310 : 0xffffff801dbf5d85 
0xffffff801d956350 : 0xffffff801dbe5763 
0xffffff801d9563a0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffff801d9563c0 : 0xffffff801da9c3dd 
0xffffff801d9564e0 : 0xffffff801da9bb96 
0xffffff801d956540 : 0xffffff801e318649 
0xffffff801d9565b0 : 0xffffff801dbe67c7 
0xffffff801d9566c0 : 0xffffff801e31e7a8 
0xffffff801d9566d0 : 0xffffff801da3c2df 
0xffffffd097648000 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648320 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648390 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd0976483b0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd0976486d0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648740 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648760 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648a80 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648af0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648b10 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097648e30 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097648ea0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097648ec0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd0976491e0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649250 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649270 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649590 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649600 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649620 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649940 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd0976499b0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd0976499d0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd097649cf0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd097649d60 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd097649d80 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a0a0 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764a110 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764a130 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a450 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
0xffffffd09764a4c0 : 0xffffff801da3ba60 
0xffffffd09764a4e0 : 0xffffff801db3c705 
0xffffffd09764a800 : 0xffffff801dbe54a8 
    Backtrace continues...

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff8573266b70): kernel_task
```

UPDATE 05-20-2022

Today my mac did panic again. Here's the stacktrace

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff00dd3a024): macOS panic detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x36894700
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000005cac000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff00ccb0000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1a0b37c0978
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x628538f2 0x000d0253
  Sleep   : 0x62879017 0x000d5999
  Wake    : 0x62879145 0x000d9afe
  Calendar: 0x6287bdc2 0x000d4e6e

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff0581b4000 - 0xfffffff0581c4000
Native    : 0xffffffe0006a0000 - 0xffffffe6006a0000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb00ab0000 - 0xffffffeb04c10000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb022b0000 - 0xffffffeb0250c000
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff00da3f13c, LR=0xfffffff00da41cf4, FP=0xffffffeb0410b910
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f2f50658: 0 pages, 230 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f38fc000, backtrace: 0xffffffeb04bdb670, tid: 443
          lr: 0xfffffff00d497388  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb6b0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d497118  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb720
          lr: 0xfffffff00d5cfeac  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb7a0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d5cf03c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb850
          lr: 0xfffffff00daf95fc  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb860
          lr: 0xfffffff00d496e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbbf0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d496e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbc50
          lr: 0xfffffff00e5eb488  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbc70
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd3a024  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbca0
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd26f5c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbd00
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd2d410  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbd50
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd28e48  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbdf0
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd26640  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbe70
          lr: 0xfffffff00dbd8db4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbea0
          lr: 0xfffffff00da3f3a4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbee0
          lr: 0xfffffff00da3ebb4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbf20
          lr: 0xfffffff00db045a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

UPDATE 06/07/2022

New kernel panic, here's the error report I got.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff00a5de024): macOS panic detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x40001000100
PCIeUp link state: not available
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000002550000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff009554000
mach_absolute_time: 0x66655ee42dc
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x628fdd51 0x000de291
  Sleep   : 0x629f4ad8 0x0003593a
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x629f4ad8 0x0004ab2f

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff04c1b4000 - 0xfffffff04c1c4000
Native    : 0xffffffe000668000 - 0xffffffe600668000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb00a78000 - 0xffffffeb04ba8000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb02278000 - 0xffffffeb024f8000
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0x0000000000000000, LR=0x0000000000000000, FP=0x0000000000000000
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f3040658: 0 pages, 231 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f30076d8, backtrace: 0xffffffeb0405b670, tid: 418
          lr: 0xfffffff009d3b388  fp: 0xffffffeb0405b6b0
          lr: 0xfffffff009d3b118  fp: 0xffffffeb0405b720
          lr: 0xfffffff009e73eac  fp: 0xffffffeb0405b7a0
          lr: 0xfffffff009e7303c  fp: 0xffffffeb0405b850
          lr: 0xfffffff00a39d5fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0405b860
          lr: 0xfffffff009d3ae2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bbf0
          lr: 0xfffffff009d3ae2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bc50
          lr: 0xfffffff00ae8f488  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bc70
          lr: 0xfffffff00a5de024  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bca0
          lr: 0xfffffff00a5caf5c  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bd00
          lr: 0xfffffff00a5d1410  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bd50
          lr: 0xfffffff00a5cce48  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bdf0
          lr: 0xfffffff00a5ca640  fp: 0xffffffeb0405be70
          lr: 0xfffffff00a47cdb4  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bea0
          lr: 0xfffffff00a2e33a4  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bee0
          lr: 0xfffffff00a2e2bb4  fp: 0xffffffeb0405bf20
          lr: 0xfffffff00a3a85a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Please uninstall HAXM according to the developer's instructions, reboot, and see whether there's an improvement.

Comment: FYI I have the same system as you and asked a similar question, in case it helps: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440445/macbook-pro-panics-way-more-than-it-should

Comment: it seems that uninstalling HAXM helped... didn't try it a lot, but will comment an update if this is not the fix

Comment: @LincD. please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @AugustoHerbel Your subsequent panic reports appear to be truncated. Are you sure you're pasting the **entire** panic report? (It should look more like your original report - containing, among other things, a line that says `Boot args:`)

Comment: @pion that’s all that I was able to get from the panic report. Is there something I can do to check if I am copying a truncated report?

Answer (score 1):

```
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.6.5
```

The problem is likely caused by HAXM. Please uninstall it according to the developer's instructions and see what happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this was one of the problems... I updated the question with another Kernel panic that was happening, but was not related to the HAXM kernel extension

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine if it is a hardware or software issue, try backing up your system, wiping the Mac, and reinstalling a fresh copy of MacOS from the internet. Then put ONLY YOUR FILES back onto the computer, and install each application, program, etc from the internet, fresh copies. If it continues to happen, it's a hardware issue - replacing all the software will ensure that the software is not to blame. (If it starts panicking suddenly after a certain program is installed, then that program is to blame.) If it doesn't happen anymore, then it was a software issue. Try the MacBook's built in diagnostics to see if that finds anything - it didn't on mine, but it could on yours. [Instructions on diagnostics here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)

Answer (score 0):

Certain classes of panics can be partially debugged by their stack dump. We always need to review panic reports with symbolicated stacks. In order to get a symbolicated report:

1. Run the following Terminal command:

   **`sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`**

   Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a general error, you will first need to **[disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection)**. You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. Reboot your machine. The next time this panic occurs, your report will have a symbolicated stack dump. Please update your question with the new report. We may then be able to narrow down the possible causes.

Comment: should I leave the SIP disabled until I have a new report? or I can just disable SIP, execute the command you suggested (sudo nvram ...), and after that re-enable SIP?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel The latter should be fine. You can confirm after reboot that symbolication is still enabled by running `sysctl kern.bootargs`

Comment: Thank you. Will do that today and update the question with a new report when I have a new kernel panic

Comment: hi @pion, I posted another panic report with the `sysctl kern.bootargs` enabled