# 2020 MacBook Pro keeps shutting down with this error

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

This is the error I keep getting.

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff8006b199a4): zone_require failed: address not in a zone (addr: 0x40) @zalloc.c:1488
Panicked task 0xffffffa4f4d22000: 10 threads: pid 110: mds
Backtrace (CPU 5), panicked thread: 0xffffff9b5be4c000, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb0b026b860 : 0xffffff800627fd6d 
0xffffffb0b026b8b0 : 0xffffff80063e1086 
0xffffffb0b026b8f0 : 0xffffff80063d03f3 
0xffffffb0b026b940 : 0xffffff800621fa70 
0xffffffb0b026b960 : 0xffffff800628013d 
0xffffffb0b026ba80 : 0xffffff800627f8f6 
0xffffffb0b026bae0 : 0xffffff8006b14e03 
0xffffffb0b026bbd0 : 0xffffff8006b199a4 
0xffffffb0b026bc10 : 0xffffff8006b19a1b 
0xffffffb0b026bc20 : 0xffffff80062ee53f 
0xffffffb0b026bc30 : 0xffffff80062de9b0 
0xffffffb0b026bc50 : 0xffffff80062658a8 
0xffffffb0b026bc80 : 0xffffff800682e963 
0xffffffb0b026bcd0 : 0xffffff800683015c 
0xffffffb0b026bdc0 : 0xffffff80068336ba 
0xffffffb0b026bec0 : 0xffffff80068334b6 
0xffffffb0b026bf40 : 0xffffff800698918b 
0xffffffb0b026bfa0 : 0xffffff8006220236 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9b5be4c000): mds
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
21G83

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Wed Aug 10 14:25:27 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.141.5~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D0DC2052-71F4-3DCB-B189-BEE5A59B3B42
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000006000000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8006200000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000006010000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8006210000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,3 (Mac-E7203C0F68AA0004)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 173

System uptime in nanoseconds: 336085889266192
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000131ab180b351b
  Sleep   : 0x000130337bf2f135 0x00001e830fac2f5a 0x0001302ec75b686f
  Wake    : 0x00013033a1970e3e 0x0000000104e25b6e 0x000130338ad7bc2d
Compressor Info: 13% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 12% of segments limit (OK) with 5 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff90270a8000 - 0xffffffb0270a8000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff90270a8000 - 0xffffff90280a9000
  . VM    : 0xffffff90280a9000 - 0xffffff94f4b0f000
  . RO    : 0xffffff94f4b0f000 - 0xffffff968e3db000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff968e3db000 - 0xffffff9b5ae41000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff9b5ae41000 - 0xffffffa0278a7000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffa0278a7000 - 0xffffffa4f430d000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffa4f430d000 - 0xffffffa9c0d74000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffa9c0d74000 - 0xffffffb0270a8000
  Metadata: 0xffffffb02b0b8000 - 0xffffffb04b0b8000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffb04b0b8000 - 0xffffffb04e0b8000

last started kext at 334453399770345: >!UAudio  416.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9f023000, size 335872)
last stopped kext at 334591759067032: >!UAudio  416.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9f023000, size 335872)
loaded kexts:
>AGPM   129
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5450.8
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
>!ABridgeAudio!C    240.6
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.5.7
>!AGFXHDA   140.3
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.5.7
>!A!IKBLGraphics    18.0.8
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!ABacklight    180.8
>!AHV   1
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.8
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   240.6
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ADiskImages2  126.141.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   583.100.10
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1934.141.2
>!A!BModule 1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!AActuatorDriver   5460.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  228.2
>!AMultitouchDriver 5460.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5460.1
>!AHS!BDriver   5450.8
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   140.1
>!AGraphicsControl  6.5.7
|IOAudio!F  340.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1040.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1040.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  597
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.8
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGPUWrangler  6.5.7
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.5.7
|IOGraphics!F   597
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.14
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1
>!AConvergedPCI 1
>!A!BDebug  1
>!A!BDebugService   1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AMultiFunctionManagerMac  1
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1040.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  533.120.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  210.120.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  456.140.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  456.140.3
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.2.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: How often does this happen? What are you doing each time it occurs? Can you post multiple copies of the panic report (using www.PasteBin.com or similar and linking to them) so that we can compare differences? What hardware is attached to your system at the time?

Comment: Hi. I was just doing flash cards when this happened. Another time I heard a loud fan noise come on maybe for like a second then it shut down. Another time it happened when I was basically doing nothing. No hardware is attached to the system.

Comment: Check your UAudio drivers are up to date - can't tell from that number which they are.

Comment: The panic signature suggests memory corruption but we need more information to see if that's a valid line to follow. One important thing you can do is enable kernel symbolication for subsequent panic reports. Please see my answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441383/404917