# Investigating why macOS sometimes completely locks up / crashes in a progressive way related to file or network access

Tags: macos, network, crash, mount

I've observed that macOS 10.15 and earlier have a pervasive, somewhat rare bug where certain situations involving network or file access can cause the entire system to progressively lockup, until nothing is responsive any longer.

The symptoms of such a crash generally play out like this:

1. Various applications on the system start to become permanently locked up. They seem responsive at first, but certain kinds of disk or network access will cause them to become locked up, with the spinning beach ball of death. I cannot at this point say precisely what it is they need to do to become locked up.
2. Attempts to force quit these locked up applications silently fail, even when using `kill -9`
3. Eventually new applications cannot be launched. Their Dock icons will bounce endlessly, or launching them from a terminal window will cause the terminal window to become permanently locked up.
4. The entire system becomes locked up -- the cursor is the spinning beach ball of death for all applications
5. If one manages to try and shut down the system using something like `sudo shutdown -r now`, the system will start to shut down, get as far as a black screen, but never actually reboot.
6. Finally the only course is to do a hard reset. After rebooting, you get the dialog box saying "You restarted the system because of a problem..."

I haven't yet found an underlying cause for this type of crash, but it generally seems to be related to intense network access, or sometimes mounted file systems. Just today I triggered it by interacting with mounted disk images. One of them suddenly became unable to be ejected, and then one application after another became locked up until the entire system crashed.

The only way to trigger this bug consistently I've found is using a BitTorrent client, specifically qBittorrent. What I can do is queue up around 10-15 torrents, selected for being several gigabytes in size and having many seeders. (I generally choose several popular torrents for Linux ISOs.) I set qBittorrent's connection limit to be 50 connections per torrent and 500 connections globally, queue up these torrents, and then start them all simultaneously. If the download speeds reach 40-50 MB/s, then macOS will reliably crash as described in about one minute. ([See this GitHub issue](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/12145) for more information regarding this.)

This bug does not seem to affect macOS Big Sur and later, or at least I cannot trigger it using the above method with qBittorrent. However I have several macs that I use regularly that cannot or should not be upgraded to Big Sur that frequently experience this issue, hence me looking for a solution.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any way I can figure out what precisely is going wrong?
2. More importantly, is there any way to work around or fix this crash?

Comment: I would start by throttling the bandwidth in qBittorrent to see if that has any effect. If so, it could possibly be a network buffer issue.

Comment: @Allan I did do some tests there, and found that both reducing the number of connections and the bandwidth delayed the issue, but never really solved it. And I can still trigger the issue when no significant network connections are involved. Such as the incident today when I was working with disk images -- and I'm not sure if they were necessarily the trigger.

Comment: It further points to a network memory\buffer issue.  Try watching memory in Activity monitor during your tests

Comment: Can you run a debug build of qBittorrent so that spin reports contain full symbolic information? And see my answer in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441239/macbook-pro-16-inch-2019-restarts-after-sleep-or-locking-the-screen/441383#441383 to enable kernel symbolication too. With both of these, you might get some more hints.